# How to make this cubic root (C++) algorithm faster?

Tags: algorithms

Okay, so this is the algorithm. It works but takes too much time.

```
float answer(float n)
{
    float x = 1;
    float y = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
    {   
        //x = (y*y)

        x = y*(n + x) / (x + y);
        y = x/y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

The algorithm is based on the equation :

$N + x = x^{3} + x$

$N + x = x(x^{2} + 1)$

$\dfrac{(N + x)}{ (x^{2} + 1)} = x$

**Update:**

We want to make sure that all $x$ have the same power.
So,

Let $y = x$

$yN = x^4$

$yN + x^2y = x^4 + x^2y$

$y(N + x^2) = x^2(x^2 + y)$

$\dfrac {y(N + x^2)}{(x^2 + y)} = x^2$

Hence, $x = y =\dfrac {x^2}{y}$

Comment: `#include <cmath>` and `float answer(float n){ return cbrt(n); }`. It's also shorter ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think the OP is trying to implement the floating-point algorithms himself for learning. Otherwise, I would have suggested: pow(n,1/3);

Comment: Are you trying to improve the implementation of *this* algorithm, or asking for a suggestion for how to formulate a *better* algorithm?

Comment: @Ian I'm trying to improve it.

Comment: BTW, not for nothing, but this is, er, suboptimal code.  For example, what is 50?  Why the two-step implementation when the equation on which it is based may be expressed in a single step?  The second step looks wasteful.  I think there are more issues here than meets the eye.

Comment: @ValentPierce OK. I think your equation setup still has some typo, because if $x=x^2/y$ for nonzero $x$ then $1/x=y/x^2$ hence $y=x$.

Comment: Yeah, y really is equal to x. @Ron, ugly code, I know. Frankly, I cannot see how this could be made into a single expression.

Comment: OK, so you start with $N=x^3$, you add $x$ to both sides, then you factor $x^2+1$ and divide both sides by that. From this you conclude that $N^{1/3}$ is a fixed point of the function $f(x)=\frac{N+x}{x^2+1}$. (Hopefully it is also a stable fixed point.) Thus you can remove $y$ entirely, by simply applying this function $f$ repeatedly.

Comment: But we need prior knowledge on the value of $x^{2}$. So, I tried to not have any terms with powers higher than 1.

Comment: In fact your method is not even guaranteed to work. A fixed point iteration for solving $f(x)=x$ by repeatedly applying $f$ will converge locally if and only if $|f'(x_0)|<1$, where $x_0$ is the fixed point. In your case $f'(N^{1/3})=\frac{1-2N^{2/3}}{N^{2/3}+1}$. This condition is violated in your case for $N \geq 2 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @ValentPierce I don't understand; what is slow about computing $\frac{N+x}{x^2+1}$ where $x$ is your current estimate? The only workaround I can really see is to write $\frac{1}{x} \frac{N+x}{x+1/x}$, which is objectively slower (try it).

Comment: @Ian I want the it to compute in five iteration or less. Like the Babylonian method.

Comment: @ValentPierce With this mathematical setup, that's just not going to happen. Again, your method doesn't even converge for $N \geq 2 \sqrt{2}$. Try it on $N=8$ with an initial guess of $1$.

Comment: @ValentPierce However, it turns out that the Babylonian method for square roots is the same as Newton's method for solving $x^2-N=0$. So you will see similar nice properties if you use that.

Comment: It works for me. Loop : 22 y = 1.99999 x = 3

Loop : 23 y = 2.00001 x = 4

Loop : 24 y = 2 x = 4.00001

Comment: @ValentPierce Hm. But then you don't have $y=x$ at the end. So we seem to be disagreeing on how the method is formulated mathematically.

Comment: In the code fragment $x$ is actually $x^2$.

Comment: The problem with most of the formulas given above is that the values of `x` and `y` keep changing during the algorithm, so it means nothing to say `x` equals some value unless you say _when_ it equals that value. A way to resolve this problem is to give each new value of `x` or `y` a new subscript: $y_0, x_0, y_1, x_1, y_2$, and so forth. Then you can discuss the algorithm mathematically without writing nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):

If you're looking for the cube root of a number $N$, then define this function:

$f\left(x\right) = x^3 - N$, with derivative $f'\left(x\right) = 3x^2$.

---

The real zero of this function will be the principle cube root of $N$. 
Let $x_0 = k$ be your "initial guess." Note that as long as $k \ne 0$, it does not matter what number you choose.

Then, we can use recursion to get increasingly accurate results.
The next value is defined as follows:

$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f\left(x_n\right)}{f'\left(x_n\right)}$

In this case, $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^3-N}{3x_n^2}$.

Comment: What's wrong with $x_0=1$?

Comment: Honestly, I really don't know where that came from... I just thought about it and decided I'm so tired I'm just making stuff up... Haha it's fixed...

Comment: Just an numerical aside, as it is about implementation: The way you wrote $x_{n+1}$ might be unstable, as $x_n^3\approx N$ and you lose precision. It is more stable and cheaper to compute $x_{n+1} = \frac23 x_n + \frac13 \frac N{x_n^2}$.

Comment: Yeah, you can't beat Newton's.

Comment: Actually, you can. There are iterations with higher rates of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

for(int i=0;i<500;i++)

If your algorithm works, 500 steps is probably too many most of the time. You might do better to test abs(x-y) < tol and break when TRUE, where tol is some acceptable small number.